# how to pass value using script to controller(laravel) php. (newbie)

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-4

1. I would like to pass the value from the textbox using script to my controller and save it on my db. The text box got its value changed but the ajax didnt work, sorry im new to this.

//script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#colorselector_1').colorselector({
        callback : function(value,color) {
        var colorit = $("#colorColor").val(color);
               $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/addItemColor',
               data: {'color':colorit},
              });             
        }
    });
});
```

//controller

```
  public function addItemColor(){
    $color = Input::get("color");
    $cake= cakeModel::find($_SESSION['cakeModelID']);
    $cake->colorlayer1=$color;
    $cake->save();
    return Redirect::to('home'); //temporary
 }
```

//html

```
    <section id="colorselectors">

    <select id="colorselector_1" >
      <option value="1" data-color="#A0522D">sienna</option>
      <option value="47" data-color="#CD5C5C" selected="selected">indianred</option>
      <option value="87" data-color="#FF4500">orangered</option>
      <option value="17" data-color="#008B8B">darkcyan</option>
      <option value="18" data-color="#B8860B">darkgoldenrod</option>
      <option value="68" data-color="#32CD32">limegreen</option>
      <option value="42" data-color="#FFD700">gold</option>
      <option value="77" data-color="#48D1CC">mediumturquoise</option>
      <option value="107" data-color="#87CEEB">skyblue</option>
      <option value="46" data-color="#FF69B4">hotpink</option>
      <option value="47" data-color="#CD5C5C">indianred</option>
      <option value="64" data-color="#87CEFA">lightskyblue</option>
      <option value="13" data-color="#6495ED">cornflowerblue</option>
      <option value="15" data-color="#DC143C">crimson</option>
      <option value="24" data-color="#FF8C00">darkorange</option>
      <option value="78" data-color="#C71585">mediumvioletred</option>
      <option value="123" data-color="#000000">black</option>
    </select>
    <input class="boxi" type="text" id="colorColor"/>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/addItemColor',
    data: {'color':colorit},
    beforeSend: function(request) {
            return request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", $("meta[name='token']").attr('content'));
    }
})
```

I think you missed the csrf token.